# JavaScript: How to turn a dictionary into a list of elements?

Tags: javascript

What is the most elegant way to turn this:

```
{
    'a': 'aa',
    'b': 'bb'
}
```

into this:

```
[
    ['a', 'aa'],
    ['b', 'bb']
]
```

Comment: Wouldn't that rather be an object to an array, not a dictionary to elements ?

Comment: The "most elegant" will depend on your personal definition of "elegant". What's the issue? You don't know how to do this, or you just don't like your solution?

Comment: Curious - why do you need it as an array? Can't you consume it as it is?

Comment: The canonical answer now is to use the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17626169/783743

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just iterate through the keys:

```
var dict = { 'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb' };
var arr = [];

for (var key in dict) {
    if (dict.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        arr.push( [ key, dict[key] ] );
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eeXKR/2/)  (updated per @Jack's comment, only add direct properties)

Comment: Don't forget the `hasOwnProperty()` check :)

Comment: even safer {}.hasOwnProperty.call(dict,key). this way in the unlikely case that the dictionary contains a key called "hasOwnProperty" this will still work

Comment: @Liviu I would use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call` then :)

Comment: @Jack There you go :) the ultra safe solution and no useless instantiations :)

Comment: A `.hasOwnProperty()` check is unnecessary code, and it's not a DRY solution. If you want to make sure there's nothing on `Object.prototype`, then test `Object.prototype`.

Comment: @Jack: And what if `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` is overwritten? These unnecessary guards never really offer safety. Safety is achieved by controlling your environment.

Comment: @Crazy So testing `Object.prototype` is DRY? How so? Also, I would probably use `Object.keys()`.

Comment: @Jack: You do it once. Once means we're not repeating ourselves. Putting `.hasOwnProperty` on every loop is repeating ourselves. Plus, you forget on one loop, and you've gained nothing. Plus there's performance cost. Plus sometimes you *want* to include inherited properties... but if you rely on `.hasOwnProperty` instead of ensuring a clean `Object.prototype`, you can't.

Comment: @Jack: Yeah, at least `Object.keys()` gives you a nice functional approach if you use Array methods. But what if someone overwrites `Object.keys`?

Comment: @Crazy I meant, you do it once and then what? What if the prototype is not clean? Would you suggest using Strategy?

Comment: @Jack: If it's not clean, then there's some code that needs to be removed, followed by an angry email to the original developer. And yes, requiring and ensuring a clean environment is precisely what I would suggest.

Comment: @McG btw, sorry for hijacking your answer to have this discussion :)

Answer (score 14):

Most JavaScript engines now support the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) function:

```js
const list = Object.entries({
    a: "aa",
    b: "bb"
});

console.log(list); // [['a', 'aa'], ['b', 'bb']]
```

For older engines, you can write a polyfill for it as follows:

```js
if (typeof Object.entries !== "function")
    Object.entries = obj => Object.keys(obj).map(key => [key, obj[key]]);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Much like Paul's answer actually :)

Comment: @Jack It's pretty much the same.

Answer (score 2):

Using [lodash.js](http://lodash.com/docs#pairs) (or [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#pairs))

```
var obj = {'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb'};

_.pairs(obj);

//[['a', 'aa'], ['b', 'bb']]
```

`lodash.js` is an aspiring successor to `underscore.js`, originated as a fork of the original project. In my opinion, a must use for anyone who values their time.

Comment: A link to lodash would help :)

Comment: Never heard of the lib before, but looks nice and it can be tailored to specific requirements :)

Comment: I highly recommend it. It's basically a superset of underscore.js, rewritten under the hood, yielding both better performance and browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a browser that supports [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var obj = {'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb'}, arr;
arr = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).map(function(e) {return [e, obj[e]];});
// [["a", "aa"], ["b", "bb"]]
```

Browser support table [**here**](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Object.getOwnPropertyNames)

---

As [Crazy Train](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2437417/crazy-train) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625663/#comment25661378_17626014), if you are only interested in enumerable properties, [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) will work too. In this example both would have the same result.

Comment: Just wondering, why `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` instead of `Object.keys`?

Comment: ...but +1 for the `.map()` solution.

Comment: @CrazyTrain `Object.keys` works too, afaik the only difference between them is `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` returns non-enumerable properties, as well as enumerable ones. It looked to me like OP wanted the entire _Object_, regardless of enumerability.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I was curious. Won't make a difference here of course, so either way. ...and yep, if OP needs non-enumerable properties, that's the way to go,.

Comment: @CrazyTrain it's good to be aware of alternatives involving enumaribility for the occasions when you're doing something where it matters. I've edited the answer to note the choice, and credited you