# Running Python commands for each JSON array

Tags: python, json

I am working on some API automation scripting that will import variables from the CLI (this is used for Ansible integration) and another option to import the variables from a JSON file, if that file exists.
If this file exists, the CLI is completely ignored.

Currently, I have my variables set up in a file named `parameters.py`:

```
jsondata = os.path.exists('data.json')
if jsondata == True:
    with open('data.json') as data_file:    
        data = json.load(data_file)
        for client in data['clients']:
            hostname = client['client']['hostname']
            type = client['client']['type']
            position = client['client']['position']
else:
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Variables')
   parser.add_argument('--hostname')
   parser.add_argument('--type')
   parser.add_argument('--position')
   args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
   hostname = args.hostname
   type = args.type
   position = args.position
```

I have multiple files that need to call upon these variables for different tasks, for example it needs to be used my `api.py` file to pull an ID

```
if parameters.hostname:
    query1 = {'name': parameters.hostname}
    v1 = requests.get(
        'http://test.com',
         params=query1)
    v2 = v1.status_code
    v3= v2.text
    v4= json.loads(v3)
    cid = v4['data'][0]['id']
```

Then the `cid` as well as other variables from `parameters.py` needs to be used in my `main.py`

```
payload = {
  "name": str(parameters.hostname),
  "cid": int(api.cid),
  "type": str(parameters.type),
  "custom_fields": {}
}

if parameters.position:
    payload['position'] = parameters.position
register = requests.post(
    'test.com',
    data=json.dumps(payload))
regstatus = register.status_code
if regstatus == 201:
    print (f'Client {parameters.hostname} has been completed.')
```

When I run this, I am able to switch between using the CLI and a `data.json` file. The script works when there is a single `[client]` in the JSON file, but when there's multiple, it only works on the last `[client]`
Example: `data.json`

```
{
    "clients": [
        {
        "client": {
        "hostname": "test",
        "type": 3,
         }
        },
        {
        "client": {
            "hostname": "test2",
            "type": 1,
            "position": "front",
        }
        }
           ]
    }
```

Output from `main.py` when using a `data.json` file:
`Client test2 has been completed.` nothing is being done with the first client. What am I doing wrong? Fairly new to Python and programming in general, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you *assign values* to *variables* from *json* in a `for loop`.
But, you see, here - >

```
for client in data['clients']:
   hostname = client['client']['hostname']
   type = client['client']['type']
   position = client['client']['position']
```

variable are just getting assigned and other operations are being done outside the `for loop`
So, in `loop` `first client` is fetched and assigned to variables. and in *second iteration* `next client` is fetched and same variables gets *reassigned* with value of `this new client`.
Hence, it is only showing result for `last client` always.

What you need to do is as follow :

```
for client in data['clients']:
   hostname = client['client']['hostname']
   type = client['client']['type']
   position = client['client']['position']
   #<do some operations here>
```

Or if you want to do these `operations` elsewhere then you can add these variables in another datatype like `list` or `dict` but this takes you to the original situation of extracting data from a `json`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation that makes sense. I need to do the `operations` elsewhere, how would I import the variables from the JSON into a `list` or `dict` then use those for my `operations`?

Comment: JSON is already like a Dict.
you can also convert a json into LIST but that will be a heavy process. 
for converting you can do something like as answered in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17625681/17920115)