# How does one detect and access numbered property names like 'entry1', 'entry2'?

Tags: javascript, parsing, data-structures, key

A data structure similar to the following provided ...

```
{
  strIngredient1: 'Olive Oil',
  strIngredient2: 'Onion',
  strIngredient3: 'Chicken Breast',

  strMeasure1: '',
  strMeasure2: '',

  keyWithNoIndexCount: '',
}
```

... needs to be processed.

How could one use a loop in order to generate the number count within keys like `strIngredient1`, `strIngredient2`, ... and so on?

I am having trouble working out which terms to search for. I want to use a for loop so each number after `strIngredient` would be `i`.

I want to grab each entry like that ... `strIngredient + i` ... and add them to an array but I do not know how to access them  like this, if it is even possible or the best way. I do not know how to link the two parts of the following pseudo code ...

```
const ingredList = [];

for(i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
  ingredList.push(response.meals[0].strMeasure ? ); 
  ingredList.push(response.meals[0].strIngredient ? ); 
}
console.log(ingredList);
```

**Edit 1**

There are also additional but non related entries in the data-structure.

**Edit 2**

There are also additional keys like `strMeasure1`, `strMeasure2`, `strMeasure3` etc. I want to access them too in addition to the already mentioned `strIngredient` based ones.

Comment: [you don't need to access every key by name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17625681/4935162)

Comment: what number are you trying to get?

Comment: There are also other non related entries in the json.

Comment: I want to get each number. The keys are named strMeasure1 strMeasure2 strMeasure3 etc. I want to generate the number each time with the loop. I want the number to be i  but I do not know how to link strMeasure and i.

Comment: to get a number from a string like `strIngredient42` you can do something like `.match(/\d+$/)[0]` against it. Now I still didn't get what exact result you're trying to achieve (an example would help), but assuming you want an array of numbers it could be `Object.keys(yourJSONObject).map(ingredient => ingredient.match(/\d+$/)[0])`

Comment: @MatthewOsborne ... The OP does not deal with JSON like shown above. JSON is both a standardized string based data interchange format and a JavaScript namespace which features the two methods `stringify` and `parse`. Thus the OP is working with a data structure which might have been parsed from a JSON string.

Comment: @MatthewOsborne ... From what was provided by the OP within the question and the following comments it is clear that The OP needs a **generic approach** in order to **parse from any given property-name the constant `key` part and the serial `index`**.

Comment: @MatthewOsborne ... Regarding the so far provided answers / solutions are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in two ways:

**A: Grab values of all keys, regardless of key:**

```js
const jsonObj = {
  "strIngredient1": "Olive Oil",
  "strIngredient2": "Onion",
  "strIngredient3": "Chicken Breast"
};

let ingredListA = Object.keys(jsonObj).map(key => jsonObj[key]);
console.log('ingredListA:', ingredListA);
```

**C: Grab values of by named & numbered keys:**

```js
const jsonObj = {
  "strIngredient1": "Olive Oil",
  "strIngredient2": "Onion",
  "strIngredient3": "Chicken Breast"
};

let ingredListB = [];
for(let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  let key = 'strIngredient' + i;
  ingredListB.push(jsonObj[key]);
}
console.log('ingredListB:', ingredListB);
```

If needed you could add a 3rd solution that is a hybrid of A and B: Loop through all object keys, use value only of key matches desired pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The OP needs a **generic approach** in order to **parse from any given property-name the constant `key` part and the serial `index`**. Like with a property name of `'strIngredient2'` where the constant key is `'strIngredient'` and the index is `'2'`.

One would achieve this via the usage of a regex like [`/(?<key>.*?\D)(?<index>\d*$)/`](https://regex101.com/r/iOTlYc/1) which features [named capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups).

The regex-based parsing is part of a callback-function which does [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the OP's provided object.

In order to stay even more generic by taking into account the renaming of some or all of the original object's property-names one would provide an object-based [**initial** (reduce) **value**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works_with_an_initial_value) which features both,

- a lookup for renaming some or all of the original property-names
- and the `result` object which will feature any entry one would expect according to the OP's acceptance-criteria and the additional renaming.

```js
function collectSerialEntry({ renaming, result }, [propName, value]) {
  const regXSerialKey = /(?<key>.*?\D)(?<idx>\d*$)/;

  let { key = null, idx = null } = regXSerialKey
    .exec(propName)
    ?.groups ?? {};

  if (key !== null) {
    key = renaming[key] ?? key;

    if (idx !== null) {
      idx = parseInt(idx, 10);
      idx = Number.isNaN(idx) && 1 || idx;

      // - create and/or access the `key` related array
      //   and assign the value according to the
      //   retrieved index.
      (result[key] ??= [])[idx - 1] = value;
    } else {
      // - assign the value according to its current key.^
      result[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return { renaming, result };
}


const sampleData = {
  strIngredient1: 'Olive Oil',
  strIngredient2: 'Onion',
  strIngredient3: 'Chicken Breast',
  strMeasure1: '100 ml',
  strMeasure2: '2',
  strMeasure3: '4',
  strDescription: 'Start frying ... lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
};


const {
  result: {
    ingredientList,
    measureList,
    description,
  },
} = Object
  .entries(sampleData)
  .reduce(collectSerialEntry, {
    // - provide an initial value ...
    renaming: {
      strIngredient: 'ingredientList',
      strMeasure: 'measureList',
      strDescription: 'description',
    },
    //   ... which features a lookup
    //   for renaming some or all of
    //   the original property-names ...
    //
    //   ...  and the `result` object
    //   which will feature any entry
    //   one would expect according to
    //   the OP's acceptance-criteria
    //   and the additional renaming.
    result: {},
  });

console.log(sampleData, ' => ', {
  ingredientList,
  measureList,
  description,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```