# For some reason, join() and toString() not working on created array. Array created from JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have created an array like this. When I try to turn it into string so I can use it, the result in the console log is blank.

```js
const measureList = Object.entries(objectMeasure)
var ingredList = []
for (i=0; i<20;i++) {
  ingredList.push(measureList[29+i][1])
  ingredList.push(measureList[9+i][1])
}
```

This is what the array looks like in the console.

```js
0 :  "1 tbsp"
1 :  "Olive Oil"
2 :  "1 chopped"
3 :  "Onion"
4 :  "200g"
5 :  "Chicken Breast"
6 :  "pinch"
7 :  "Ginger"
8 :  "2 tblsp "
9 :  "Harissa Spice"
10 :  "10"
11 :  "Dried Apricots"
12 :  "220g"
13 :  "Chickpeas"
14 :  "200g"
15 :  "Couscous"
16 :  "200ml"
17 :  "Chicken Stock"
18 :  "Handful"
19 :  "Coriander"
20 :  ""
21 :  ""
22 :  ""
23 :  ""
24 :  ""
25 :  ""
26 :  ""
27 :  ""
28 :  ""
29 :  ""
30 :  ""
31 :  ""
32 :  ""
33 :  ""
34 :  ""
35 :  ""
36 :  ""
37 :  ""
38 :  ""
39 :  ""
```

I want that as a string. This is the first time I have tried this so I am not sure what I am doing.

[image: console screenshot]

Line 92 in the image is the result of:

```js
console.log(ingredList.join(" "))
```

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: buildApiUrl({
    query: 'lookup',
    value: 52850,
  }),
}).then(response => {
  console.log(response);

  const objectMeasure = response.meals[0];
  const measureList = Object.values(objectMeasure);

  const ingredList = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    let key = '.strMeasure' + i;
    // ingredList.push(objectMeasure[key]);
    // console.log(ingredList);
    console.log(measureList);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    // console.log(measureList[29+i][1]);
    // console.log(measureList[9+i][1]);
    ingredList.push(measureList[29 + i]);
    ingredList.push(measureList[9 + i]);
    // console.log(ingredList);
  }

  console.log(ingredList.join(" "));
});
```

Comment: have you tried using `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: Can you please format the data object as JS, and add those in a code block to the question.

Comment: Paste an entire working example, otherwise there is too much guessing required to figure out what is going on

Comment: You might want to try `Object.values()` instead. Entries returns an Array of arrays with each key and its value as the two members of the sub array. Or `Object.entries(array).map(v => v[0]).join( ',' )` or something

Comment: Why are you indexing `measureList` starting at 9 and 29?

Comment: JSON.parse() gives unexpected end of JSON ... error

Comment: I have changed it to Object.values() and I have the same issue.

Comment: I am indexing at 9 and 29 because that is where the information I need is. The food name starts at 9 and the measurement at 29

Comment: 1/2 ... This question obviously [is related to another one of the OP, asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75077209/how-does-one-detect-and-access-numbered-property-names-like-entry1-entry2). The only thing the OP needs to do is to provide the JSON string and/or the parsed and formatted data of the JSON response and the expected result (the target format) of the OP's source data. Nobody is capable of remotely debugging the OP's application by guessing from the little and not precisely provided information from either of the OP's questions.

Comment: 2/2 ... And regarding the OP's title ... _"For some reason, join() and toString() not working on created array"_ ... `join('')` and `toString()` will work on every array. Thus one needs to have a look into the OP's array creating process which connects this current thread to the above linked one from yesterday. **btw** ... from the console snapshot provided by the OP it looks like the OP has created an array of arrays where each nested array features always exactly two items.

Comment: @MatthewOsborne ... please provide the entire data of `objectMeasure` which got assigned from the `response`-objects first `meal`-item ... `const objectMeasure = response.meals[0];`. Also do provide the expected structure/content of `ingredList` in order to let us countercheck the array creating process.